# Is there a reason we cannot name a non-static member function in an unevaluated context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

When reading [[expr.prim.id]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id), one will see that

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

The fact that the bullet above applies only to data members is unclear to me. Intuitively I'd expect the following to be well formed:

```
#include <type_traits>

using func = int();

class bar {
  func foo; // This is valid, and not the subject of the question
};

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(bar::foo), func>::value, "No Symmetry!");
```

But the `decltype()` is ill-formed even before the static assertion is checked.

Is there some ambiguity I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some ambiguity I'm missing?

The fact there's a whole lot of type information that is added as part of that member function declaration.

While `func` may certainly be used to declare that member, the story doesn't end here. Once the member is declared, it's type is completed. That involves adding a couple of other things, like *cv-qualifers* and *ref-qualifiers*. In the case of `foo`, all the default implicit ones are determined, and they become part of `bar::foo`'s type. As specified by [[dcl.fct]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#8):

> The return type, the parameter-type-list, the ref-qualifier, the
>   cv-qualifier-seq, and the exception specification, but not the default
>   arguments, are part of the function type.

There's no way to specify them explicitly in the above declaration of `foo` (though they may be added to `func`), but they may be added in general:

```
class bar {
  int foo() const volatile &&;
};
```

They are part of the function type, and `decltype(bar::foo)` should address them if they appear (and if I gather correctly, even if they don't).

Where does the `const volatile &&` go when we attempt to evaluate `decltype(bar::foo)`?

- Should it be ignored? That can be done. But losing type information is rarely a good thing.
- Should we retain it, and the type `decltype` evaluates to be a pointer to a member function, instead?
  That too would work, but now it's different from how data members would behave when named in an unevaluated context. We introduce a discrepancy.
- Should it be retained, and the type resolved to something else? Perhaps something like `int(foo const volatile&&)` or `int() const volatile &&` (another form of function type)? That breaks the symmetry one would expect to have, and is again a discrepancy to data members.

There is no easy or obvious way in which allowing it would always work well. So rather than complicate matters for a feature that would see limited use, it's better to regard it as ill-formed.

Comment: Unless [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) is out-of-date, It seems that you can, in fact, put `const volatile &&` into the typedef.

Comment: @Quentin - You can put it on `func`, you cannot add it after the fact on `bar::foo`. I clarified what I meant.

Comment: You mean no `func foo const;`? Alright, but how would that be a rationale which prevents `decltype(bar::foo)` from producing a fully-qualified function type, i.e. `int() const volatile &&` in your example?

Comment: @Quentin - Well, for one thing: As is, `func` may be used to define both members and free functions. I suppose it's again about discrepancy with data members. For a data member, the type won't "change" just because it's a member.

Comment: That's debatable: `decltype` of a data member is specifically defined to be its "base" type (as if it was a free variable), but then taking `&Foo::bar` will yield different types depending on whether the data member `bar` is `static` or not. Maybe I'm confused, but to me `decltype` symmetry with data members would be achieved by returning the qualified function type, even if that type is "abominable" and thus hardly usable.

Comment: @Quentin Seems to me the whole thing is quite a mess and it was just decided it wasn't worth the effort to give meaning to `decltype(member function)`

Comment: @PasserBy - My conclusion as well, at the end of the day.

Comment: I don't know, I think I agree with Quentin that it's "obvious" if `decltype(bar::foo)` did work, your example should result in `int()const volatile&&`. (And if `foo` were overloaded, the program would just be ill-formed.) I more think it just wasn't considered useful enough to specify and implement.

Comment: What symmetry does it break, if it would have `int() const volatile&&`? I can do `typedef int func() const volatile &&;` It seems a symmetry to me. Why would this be "another form of function type"?

Comment: @geza - On the one hand, `func` can be used to declare both member functions, and free functions. But as far as I see it, `decltype(bar::foo)` would return a type that *cannot* be used to declare free functions. My postulation is that it would have to contain "invisible parts" that pertain to the cv-qualifier and ref-qualifer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, that's a question. For me, it is logical that `decltype(bar::foo)` could return `func`. And it could be used to declare a free function. It is not a member function pointer, but a function type, afterall. I don't really understand your comment about "invisible parts". `decltype(bar::foo)` should return a type which contains qualifiers. Just like I can put qualifiers to a typedef'd function type.

Comment: @geza- I talk about "invisible part" because `bar::foo`'s complete type as a member function has to account for const qualifiers and ref qualifier. Even if we don't do it explicitly, it's still there, isn't it? (At least I hope)..

Comment: @StoryTeller: Hmm. Maybe I don't understand something fundamental. What do you mean by this: "func is an alias to an incomplete type."

Comment: @geza - Oh, that? I recall [\[basic.types\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#def:type,function) referring to function types (as specified by [\[dcl.fct\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#8)) as incomplete. Though that wording isn't there now. Now it just makes distinctions between object types and non-object types. Then again maybe my memory is failing me.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Hmm, then I still don't understand you about the hidden part. If `func` doesn't contain qualifiers, then it will declare a member function without qualifiers. If it contains, then the member function will have it. `decltype(bar::foo)` would give a function type with qualifiers (if there are any).

Comment: The qualifiers are part of the implicit object parameter; `void f() const volatile &&` behaves similarly to a free function `void bar_f(bar const volatile&&)` with calls `x.f()` transformed to `bar_f(x)`.  It is "asymmetric" against data members because the type of data members do not get "called" and so do not have the implicit object parameter.

Comment: @M.M - That's precisely the point I was trying to get across. Though without mentioning the `this` parameter.

Comment: I came across [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#6), that illustrates a usage for a cv-qualified function type

Comment: Why can I do [`std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(&S::f)>;`](https://godbolt.org/z/MFuKGt) if `decltype(S::f)` has no sense?

Comment: @YSC - Note that `&S::f` is a pointer to member, so not disallowed. And [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) just preserves that type as is. It doesn't remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some ambiguity I'm missing?

I don't think so. It's probably more that there was a definite need to evaluate non-static data members and not so much for non-static member functions.

However, this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(bar::foo), func>::value, "No Symmetry!");
```

doesn't make much sense. The type of `&bar::foo` is not `func*`, it's `func bar::*`. And there isn't a way to spell that without a pointer, so having to be able to evaluate `decltype(bar::foo)` means introducing whole new type syntax? Doesn't seem worth it.

Note that `decltype(bar::foo)` cannot be `func` because `func` is a function type, but `bar::foo` is a member function.

Comment: It is `decltype(bar::foo)`, without the `&`.

Comment: Then I don't understand your answer. Why do you talk about pointers, when the question doesn't have any? `decltype(bar::foo)` could return `int()`, I don't see any problems with this.

Comment: @geza Because that would make no sense. Its type most certainly isn't `int()`.

Comment: Why? Decltype'ing a member variable, it gives its type, without being "specialized" for the enclosing class. We could have the same for functions.

Comment: I mean, you can downvote this if you want, but there's no way to spell the type "member function", so there's no meaningful thing for `decltype(bar::foo)` to return.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I understand your point, but I don't agree with it. For me, it is completely fine that `decltype(bar::foo)` returns `int()`. For you, it is not. It's not a big deal. I just don't understand, if `func` was used to declare a function (no matter, free or member), then why you think that its type is not `func` in the member case. If the language allows you to declare a member function with the type `func`, then it is logical for me that its type is `func`.

Comment: @geza It's not a matter of opinion. `decltype(bar::foo)` **cannot** be `int()` - this would imply that you could take a normal function pointer to it, but you cannot. The type would have to be `int() bar::`, but that's not valid syntax in C++ today.

Comment: with this logic, if `bar` has an `int member;`, then `decltype(bar::member)` should not be a `int`, because when you make a pointer from it, then you cannot assign it to a member pointer.

Comment: @geza **No**. If `bar` has `int member`, then you **can** take an `int*` to it.

Comment: But you need an instance. For me, this is backward thinking, sorry. You say, that for member function type, it should have `bar::` integrated. For member variables, you say that it should not, because you can make a pointer from it, and point it to an actual `int`. But this is not the same, because you need an instance in this case. For consistency, if you think that member function type should integrate `bar::` into its type, then member variable should integrate `bar::` into its type too, so when you make a pointer from it, you get a member variable pointer (and not a simple one).

Comment: This is interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455800/how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-member-function. Quote from the standard: "The type of a non-static member function is an ordinary function type, and the type of a non-static data member is an ordinary object type."

Comment: To add onto what @geza said, the specialness of a member function pointer is stated in [[basic.compound](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3)]: _Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members._

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any reason.

Look at this:

```
typedef void Func();

Func freeFunction;

struct Foo {
    Func memberFunction;
};
```

`freeFunction`'s declaration is `Func freeFunction;`. So, `decltype(freeFunction)` is `void()`, i.e. `Func`.

Using the same logic, As `Foo::memberFunction` is declared as `Func` too, I'd expect `decltype(Foo::memberFunction)` to be `Func` too. But that's not the case, as this doesn't compile.

Just like a `int a; decltype(a)` resolves to `int`, even if `int a;` is a member, `decltype(Foo::memberFunction)` should be OK.

Note, that qualifiers can be handled too, there is nothing special about them (of course, in this case, `Func` can only be used for declaring non-static member functions):

```
typedef void Func() const volatile &&;

struct Foo {
    Func memberFunction;
};
```

Here, I'd expect that `decltype(Foo::memberFunction)` to be `void() const volatile &&`, so I can copy its declaration:

```
struct Bar {
    decltype(Foo::memberFunction) myMemFn;
};
```

---

Quote from the C++14 standard (9.2/11):

> [ Note: The type of a non-static member function is an ordinary
>   function type, and the type of a non-static data member is an ordinary
>   object type. There are no special member function types or data member
>   types. — end note ]

This quote means that it would be sensible, if `decltype(<member_function>)` returned a type of ordinary function.

Comment: So then why does the standard not allow it?

Comment: @RustyX: good question. I don't know. Maybe there is a good reason for not allowing it, but I don't see it. I don't quite agree with StoryTeller's explanation. And there has been no other ideas given yet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question , all you say is that you don't know and you expect some stuff

Comment: @M.M: no. I say that I don't see any reasons. Possibly because there isn't any. Btw., are my expectations wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're forgetting about the implicit object parameter that member functions have

Comment: @M.M: why does it matter here? We're talking about function types here, not *pointer* to (member) functions.

Comment: @geza Member functions don't have types . But if they did it would have to involve the implicit object parameter, as that is a part of any call to the function

Comment: @M.M: Then why can we decltype a member variable? It needs an object as well, just like a member function. Again, we're talking about function types, not member function pointers. Types, with which one can declare a function. **Both standalone and member function**.

Comment: Variables don't have implicit object parameters. Each instance of a class has its own copy of the variables,  but there is only one function which , in functional terms, takes a reference to an instance as parameter. The parameters of a function are part of its type.  There is no such thing as a "Foo::int" for example, there are just `int`s .

Comment: @M.M: member variables do have implicit object parameters (otherwise how could you access it? - I wouldn't call it object parameter, but an object is needed). Just like member function pointers. And, that's right, there is no `Foo::int` type. Using the same principle, there is no `Foo::Func` type, just `Func` type. Don't you see the asymmetry here? One can declare a member function with using `Func`, but then its type cannot be queried resulting `Func`? `memberFunction`'s type could be simply `Func`, not something like `Foo::Func`. Just like a member's type is just `int`, not `Foo::int`.

Comment: The type of a member function declared as `Func` is not `Func`. Calling it requires one extra parameter (which syntactically appears before the function call parentheses), and the parameters are part of the type. Data members don't work like that. You can use `int *` to point to a data member int. You cannot use `Func *` to point to a member function. Sorry I will not make any more responses now, I have done my best to try and explain and I am just repeating myself

Comment: @M.M: Me too :)

Comment: @M.M: This is interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455800/how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-member-function. Quote from the standard: "The type of a non-static member function is an ordinary function type, and the type of a non-static data member is an ordinary object type."