# How do you get the type of a member function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The question is inspired by a note in the standard [[class.mem]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#16)

> The type of a non-static member function is an ordinary function type, and the type of a non-static data member is an ordinary object type. There are no special member function types or data member types.

So, I decided to test it

```
struct S
{
    using Fn = void();
    Fn foo;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), Fn>);
};
```

But its an error at `decltype(foo)`: *invalid use of non-static member fucntion*.

How do you get the type of a member function? Or is the note just bogus?

Note: It is valid to do this to data members

```
struct U
{
    int i;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), int>);
};
```

Note2: I'm not looking for how to grab the type through a pointer-to-member

```
template<typename>
struct NotLikeThis;
template<typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct NotLikeThis<R (C::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = R(Args...);
};
```

The note from the standard is irrelevant to this.

Comment: You just don't, it would seem. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263793/is-there-a-reason-we-cannot-name-a-non-static-member-function-in-an-unevaluated

Comment: I wonder what's the purpose of this note, if we can't `decltype` a member_function.

Comment: @geza Exactly my thought

Comment: @StoryTeller I remember that. I'm wondering if its possible to get the type at all.

Comment: You can do `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(&S::foo), Fn S::*>);` to check type of non-static member but I'm not sure if that was your question.

Comment: @ÖöTiib As you have suspected, it is exactly __not__ my question, as said in the second note

Comment: The answer seems to be then that "it is not specified how to get type of non-static member functions in C++."

Answer (score 1):

The standard explicitly states that you can't do this.

> ### [[expr.prim.id]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id)
>
> [2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2)  An [id-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#nt:id-expression) that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class **can only be used**:
>
> [(2.1)](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2.1)
>       as part of a [class member access](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref) in which the object expression refers to the member's class<sup>[58](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#footnote-58)</sup> or a class derived from that class, or
>
> [(2.2)](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2.2)
>       to form a pointer to member ([[expr.unary.op]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op)), or
>
> [(2.3)](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2.3)
>       if that [id-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#nt:id-expression) denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   int m;
> };
> int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
> int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
> ```
>
> — end example
>        ]

Note my emphasis on *can only be used*: Those are the only ways that you can use an expression denoting a member function. Any other way you can come up with is ill-formed.

Note that 2.3 is exactly what you want to to - to use `S::m` (`m` being a member function) in an unevaluated context (i.e.: `decltype`), but it specifically (and I would assume *deliberately*) only applies to *data* members.

I can think of at least one implication of allowing this (See below). There's probably more.

- Let's assume `m` is declared as `void m();` and it is a member of class `S`. If `decltype(S::m)` is valid, then `std::add_pointer<decltype(S::m)>` should also be valid.
  Considering that member functions have the implicit `this` parameter,
  what would this second type be? `void (S::*)()`, or maybe something
  like `void (*)(S*)`? Or even `void (*)()`? It may be obvious to us that we want `void (S::*)()`, but knowing that `S::m` is just a regular function type, why would `add_pointer` turn it into a pointer-to-member? How could it even differentiate it?