# What are the Value Category Properties of Member Functions in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Reading about value categories in C++11 onwards on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), I find it hard to understand the motivation for having member functions be prvalues.

> `a.m`, the member of object expression, where `m` is a ... non-static member function

Except, they're not really prvalues because their only property is that they can be invoked.

> The expressions `a.mf` ... [and friends] ... are classified as prvalue expressions, but they cannot be used ... for any purpose at all, except as the left-hand argument of the function call operator

Furthermore, how does C++17 temporary materialization interact with the value category of member functions? From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization),

> Temporary materialization occurs ... when performing a member access on a class prvalue

It makes more sense to me in general that functions are non-modifiable lvalues. That is, they have a defined location. I understand that in the case of a virtual member function that there is no compile time location, so I see why that case would not be an lvalue. I also see that a temporarily materialized class' member function also may have no compile time location and might not be an lvalue, although the member function is still compiled somewhere and has a location (C++ may simply make it impossible to refer to that location on the language level).

What is most confusing for me is that the compiler will not ultimately treat a non-virtual member function any differently than any other function. The only difference is name mangling. So why in the world do they belong to different value categories?

There must be some compelling reason that member functions are not lvalues when they have a well defined location. This is some real muddy water. Can somebody provide motivation and clarification?

Comment: Sorry something went wrong with my edit, clashed with yours.

Comment: @Mat I re-redited, no big deal. Thanks for making it pretty (:

Comment: A lvalue denotes the storage in which it occupies. `a.mf` the _member_ doesn't occupy any storage. You take the address of `decltype(a)::mf`.

Comment: I'm surprised `a.m` have a value category at all, while not having a type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It does have a type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455800/how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-member-function

Answer (score 1):

Non-static member functions *don't* have "a well defined location". The "location" of a virtual member function is unknown (in general) at compile-time. And even ignoring that, the "location" of member functions is never really handled in C++.

Yes, there are "pointers to member functions", but notice that these types are *not* convertible to pointers to other things. The standard doesn't even allow implementations to permit conversion to integers and back via `reinterpret_cast` the way it does for normal pointers. They're not "pointers" in the sense of memory addresses.

Member functions do not have locations in the same sense that other C++ things do. So classifying them as prvalues make sense.

> Furthermore, how does C++17 temporary materialization interact with the value category of member functions?

Temporary materialization applies to *objects*; a member function is not an object. Note what you quote: "when performing a member access on a **class prvalue**". Member functions are not classes, so they don't apply.

> What is most confusing for me is that the compiler will not ultimately treat a non-virtual member function any differently than any other function.

How the compiler implements the standard is irrelevant. The standard declares them to be prvalues, so that's what they are.

Comment: You misread the quoted section that you are telling me I misread. Performing a member access on a class prvalue means the object is the class prvalue and the member is some member of it, which may be a member function.

Comment: I am down voting you until you remove "How the compiler implements the standard is irrelevant." Note that I would like to up vote your answer, but that is a particularly heinous thing to way >:

Comment: @okovko I don't think you understood. Member functions aren't objects. Temporary materialization appertains to objects, therefore they have nothing to do with member functions.

Comment: @PasserBy The object can have a member function.

Comment: @okovko And how does that affect in any way your question about temporary materialization and member functions? The object gets materialized, but still nothing to do with member functions.

Comment: @PasserBy I don't see what else I can say to be clearer, so we have reached an impasse, unless you want to chat about it directly maybe.

Comment: @okovko: "*that is a particularly heinous thing to way*" "Heinous" or not, it's still true. The standard says what it says *regardless* of how implementers implement it.

Comment: @okovko: "*Performing a member access on a class prvalue means the object is the class prvalue and the member is some member of it, which may be a member function.*" Right. So the situation is `SomePrvalue.memberName`. That is, the temporary being materialized is the *object*, not the *member*. It is `SomePrvalue` which is being materialized.

Comment: @NicolBolas I will change to up vote (once you edit your answer in some way, I am not allowed to until you do) because I appreciate your help but it makes me sad in my heart that you feel that way. You are correct about the temporary materialization. I only meant to say that would be strange to locate a member function of a temporary object.

Comment: @okovko: "*it makes me sad in my heart that you feel that way*" I'm not sure why. The standard decides what C++ is; implementations (aka, compilers) implement C++. The definition of a prvalue comes from the standard, not from compilers. That's just the way it is.

Comment: @NicolBolas C++ is a systems level programming language and fundamental abstractions such as value categories must represent the machine model, not the C++ philosophy. It does that pretty well overall.

Comment: @okovko: "*fundamental abstractions such as value categories must represent the machine model, not the C++ philosophy*" But that is very much *not* why those value categories came to exist. "Prvalue", "xvalue", and "lvalue" have *nothing at all* to do with "the machine model". The "machine model" doesn't care if you assign to a temporary, but C++ philosophy very much does. The "machine model" doesn't care if you implicitly move from a stack variable, but C++ philosophy does. These terms don't exist for the purpose of "the machine model" at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe then C++ is a bad candidate for a systems programming language. In the context of systems programming, time spent debating the language specification is time wasted. Anyway, the value categories are pretty close to perfect. But it is simply funny to call a member function a prvalue. You know that, I know that. You say it's because the standard says so, I present the absurdity of an lvalue to a member function due to the design of C++. I guess we can move on. Can you tell I prefer C?

Comment: @okovko: "*In the context of systems programming, time spent debating the language specification is time wasted.*" That's the part I don't understand. If you feel that way, why do you *care* about value categories at all? If a language is just "whatever my compiler says it is", then what does it matter how the standard defines something that does not matter to the compiler one bit? You cannot simultaneously care about what the specification says and denigrate it as "time wasted".

Comment: @NicolBolas I have a job interview coming up! XD I prefer to spend my nerd time reading about CPU architectures than learning language specifications. I don't really care what language I am using, I write whatever is idiomatic. The less effort I have to expend writing idiomatic code the better. Although, I think to the compiler, value categories do matter quite a bit for checking. Hey, thank you for engaging with me and for all the help, Nicol. It was fun and very informative.

Answer (score 0):

After a little thought, it becomes obvious why member functions as lvalues would be absurd. Any member function has an implicit argument parameter `this` which is abstracted away from the C++ language level. As a result, an lvalue to a member function would have no context for `this`, and it would be useless as there would be no way to invoke it.

Furthermore, virtual classes have an additional hidden virtual pointer member. Virtual member functions already can't be lvalues because they're irresolute at compile time, but the virtual pointer member would also be lost because it is retrieved from `this`, so this is a second reason that a virtual member function cannot be an lvalue.

I consider this a mistake in the design of C++ and the dubbing of member functions as "prvalues" a gross cover up. If there were no hidden parameters, then member functions would be lvalues (callable by passing a reference to the object). Furthermore, if there were no hidden class members and if the virtual table wasn't hidden, then the virtual table could be queried to retrieve lvalues to virtual functions at run-time (currently this is not possible in C++ at all). Of course then the implementation of virtual functions would be specified, but that is not a bad, uncommon, nor unprecedented thing given that RVO and copy elision exist.

Comment: "*virtual functions have an additional hidden __vptr parameter*" No, they do not. And I don't even mean in terms of the standard; I am not aware of any implementation that gives virtual functions an additional parameter. Vtable lookup usually happens outside of the virtual function, as a prelude to making the actual call. "*if the virtual table wasn't hidden*" then it wouldn't be possible to implement C++ *without* vtables. Vtables are implementation details because they're not the only way of implementing virtual functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas You know, every object of a class with a virtual function needs a pointer to the single virtual table for the class. I'm getting this from [Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf). Is it out of date? I see your point about making the vtable available at the language level, but it is a waste of everybody's time to pretend that anyone will ever implement it another way.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I see what you're saying. The virtual pointer is never passed to the function. It's resolved before the call. Thank you for the correction.