# How to deduce `std::function` parameters from actual function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, std-function

Given a class

```
class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<const Bar> quux(const std::string&, std::uint32_t);
}
```

I can declare an `std::function` that has the same interface:

```
std::function<std::shared_ptr<const Bar>(const std::string&, std::uint32_t)> baz = ...
```

Is there a way of compressing that declaration such that the template arguments to `std::function` are derived from the declaration of that method, something like:

```
std::function<functype(X::quux)> baz = ...
```

where `functype` is an imaginary C++ operator similar to `decltype`. Is there a way to do this / does [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) have such a capability?

I do see that the method has a slightly different signature actually as it would also take a reference/pointer to the `this` object; it would be fine for me to derive such a signature too.

Comment: strictly speaking, no, this is not the "same" interface. You need an object of the class to call a member method. The `std::function` as you declared it is a free function. small but big difference

Comment: If you have a free function `quux`, then `decltype(quux)` will give you the function type, so `std::function<decltype(quux)> baz = quux` will work.

Comment: @Scheff We have better ways nowadays than the pre-C++11 solutions there...

Comment: @Holt Actually, [it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455800/how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-member-function).

Comment: @PasserBy Right, my point was that you cannot store `quux` directly inside `std::function<std::shared_ptr<const Bar>(const std::string&, std::uint32_t)>`.

Comment: @user463035818 That's what I'm pointing out in my last paragraph.

Comment: C++17 class template argument deduction gives you just that: it can infer it's template argument with a given function object or function pointer.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I am stuck with C++11 in the project I am working on. The accepted solution worked just fine for me though :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Adapting [How do I get the argument types of a function pointer in a variadic template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/how-do-i-get-the-argument-types-of-a-function-pointer-in-a-variadic-template-cla) to your request, we get:

```
template<typename T> 
struct function_traits;  

template<typename R, typename C, typename ...Args> 
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = std::function<R(Args...)>;
};

class Bar;

class Foo {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<const Bar> quux(const std::string&, std::uint32_t);
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::is_same<
     std::function<std::shared_ptr<const Bar>(const std::string&, std::uint32_t)>,
     function_traits<decltype(&Foo::quux)>::type>::value << std::endl;
}
```

To make it work with constant methods you will need another specialization:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename ...Args> 
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = std::function<R(Args...)>;
};
```

But you will get problems with overloaded methods, because in order to resolve overloading you will need to specify the arguments anyway.

Comment: Works like a charm! I have never seen this `C::*` syntax, the asterisk in particular - what does it do?

Comment: @scravy, it is how [pointers to member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) are declared.