# Is decltype of a non-static member function ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17, decltype

I'm not sure to perfectly understand [`[dcl.type]/4.3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#simple-4.3):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - (4.3) otherwise, if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or **if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed**;
> - [...]

For me, the emphasized part both apply to *id-expression* and *class member access*, right?

Playing with my favorite compiler, I get the following.

#### ✓ Accepted by the compiler

```
namespace N { void f() {} }
using type = decltype(N::f);
type* pf = N::f;
```

Ok I guess; `N::f` is an unparenthesized id-expression and does not name a set of overloaded functions.

#### ✗ Rejected by the compiler

```
namespace N { void f() {} void f(int) {} }
using type = decltype(N::f); // error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
type* pf = N::f;
```

Ok; `N::f` does name a set of overloaded functions.

#### ✗ Rejected by the compiler

```
struct S { void f(){} };
using type = decltype(S::f); // error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void S::f()'
type* pf = &S::f;
```

Hum? `S::f` would name a set of one overloaded function?

---

All in all, is my understanding of `[dcl.type]/4.3` just bad? is gcc trunk wrong? both? none? kamoulox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple reason is that the use of `S::f` is constrained for class members.

> **[expr.prim.id]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id#2) An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or
> non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or
> - to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

The last bullet, the one related to your code, only applies to non-static data member. There is no provision for functions.

I can only speculate as to why it's not allowed, [though I previously asked that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263793/is-there-a-reason-we-cannot-name-a-non-static-member-function-in-an-unevaluated).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth a note that `decltype(&S::f)` works here as pointer-to-member-function type,

again unless the `f` names a set of overloaded (member) functions.

The function type itself can be extracted from the pointer-to-member-function type.

If the member function is cv-or-ref qualified then it has an [abominable function type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html).

The std traits are lacking here - a library like [Boost.CallableTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/) helps.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. Note though this question is tagged [tag:language-lawyer]. It generally means we're not looking for a solution or a workaround, but for a reason/a quote from the Standard.