# C++ Get type of a member function (return type and signature) without the 'const' qualifier of the member function

Tags: c++, function, types, constants, member

Is it possible to get the type of a member function (return type and signature) without the 'const' qualifier of the member function?

I tried it so far with decltype(T) and std::remove_const / std::decay.

Example:

```
void Func(std::string, int) const -> void(std::string, int)
```

Edit for clarification:

What I have:

```
void Func(std::string, int) const
```

What I want:

```
void(std::string, int)
```

Comment: `void Func(std::string, int) const -> void(std::string, int)` is **invalid C++**. 1) You can't return a function from a function. 2) You can both write `void` and use `->` in return type.

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You say you've tried `decltype` etc so you should show your exact code in your question.

Comment: [Is decltype of a non-static member function ill-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520276/is-decltype-of-a-non-static-member-function-ill-formed)

Comment: [The standard explicitly states that you can't do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689493/12002570)

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find plenty of related SO questions. TLDR; [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689493/12002570).

Comment: @Jason I do not think the OP wants to return a function, I think OP is rather searching for a template magic which can convert a pointer to const member function to a pointer to non-const member function (for unknown reasons). I.e. convert `ret_type (Class::*)(Args...) const` to `ret_type (Class::*)(Args...)`. But OP should clarify the desired syntax usage.

Comment: @Quimby Yeah they may be looking for some template magic which should be clarified by giving some [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which should have an actual class and an actual member function and the expected result. I think OP want to convert `ret_type (Class::)(Args...) const` to `ret_type(Args...)`. Should we reopen now? Or maybe later when OP clarifies further with an actual class. As of now, at the end of their question, they have given an example of converting `void Func(std::string, int) const
` to `void (std::string, int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of doing this using [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```
struct C
{
    void Func(std::string, int) const;
    void Bar(int);
};
template<typename T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct GetType
{
    using type = Ret(Args...);
    GetType(Ret (T::*)(Args...) const) 
    {

    }
    GetType(Ret (T::*)(Args...) ) 
    {

    }

};


int main()
{
    
    using ret1 = decltype(GetType(&C::Func))::type; // void(std::string, int) as expected
    using ret2 = decltype(GetType(&C::Bar))::type;  //void(int)               as expected 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rd49WW8ef)

Comment: Ah, clever to use CTAD to avoid transformation trait specialization hell. +1. (I guess C++23's "deducing this" + CTAD will make this trait class even briefer, for all ref/const/volatile qualifier permutations).

Comment: @dfrib Yeah thanks. I wrote it earlier when OP asked the question but then closed the question as it seemed very similar to the dupe. Then I saw you reopened it so decided to paste that solution.

Comment: very cool and so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll rewrite the problem to more clearly describe what I perceive it to be, to emphasize its potential weirdness ([XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?):

- You want to strip the implicit object parameter from a member function type and present the remaining type info as a non-member function type.

You could do this by implementing a type transformation trait:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct mem_fn_to_fn_without_implicit_obj_parameter {};

// Specialization for const member functions
template <typename ReturnType, typename ClassType, typename... Args>
struct mem_fn_to_fn_without_implicit_obj_parameter<ReturnType (ClassType::*)(
    Args...) const> {
  using type = ReturnType(Args...);
};

// Specialization for non-const member functions
template <typename ReturnType, typename ClassType, typename... Args>
struct mem_fn_to_fn_without_implicit_obj_parameter<ReturnType (ClassType::*)(
    Args...)> {
  using type = ReturnType(Args...);
};

// Helper alias
template <typename T>
using mem_fn_to_fn_without_implicit_obj_parameter_t =
    typename mem_fn_to_fn_without_implicit_obj_parameter<T>::type;
```

Note that as the specialization need to match ref-, const- and volatile-qualifiers exactly, you'd need a few more permutations to cover all potential permutations of them (`const &`, `&&`, `const &&`, `volatile ...`). The example above covers only a single `const` or no qualifiers.

Example usage:

```
struct Foo {
  void func(std::string, int) const {}
};
using mem_fn_type = decltype(&Foo::func);
using slightly_similar_fn_type =
    mem_fn_to_fn_without_implicit_obj_parameter_t<mem_fn_type>;
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<slightly_similar_fn_type, void(std::string, int)>);
```

Note that `#1` will fail as soon as your overload `func` of `Foo`.

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kir4lOY1Yq0N5rGy).