# std::same_as on member function works with visual studio but not on clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I am using trait `std::same_as` to compare two types but only msvc [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/bWK38Wvr3) the program while gcc and clang both rejects it. The program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 
struct D
{
    int func(int);
};
int main()
{ 
    std::cout << std::same_as <decltype(D::func), int >;   //compiled by msvc but rejected by clang and gcc 
}
```

Clang gives the error:

```
error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    std::cout << std::same_as <decltype(D::func), int >;
```

I want to know what is the correct behavior of the program. Also, I'm using C++20.

Comment: Non static member function `D::func` usage is wrong in C++. You might want `&D::func`.

Comment: @273K Note carefully OP has already used `/permissive` in their given [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bWK38Wvr3) and msvc accepts the program even then.

Comment: @Jason I can't see it on my phone. That is why the question on so must contain all relevant information.

Comment: @Jason, `/permissive` is counterproductive for conformance, it's `/permissive-` that should be used.

Comment: @273K I see....

Comment: @chris Even with `/permissive-` the program [works](https://godbolt.org/z/3s4YEW1fz).

Comment: Note that its type would be `int(int)` if you _could_ name it that way (but that doesn't affect compilation here).

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, I guess a trait such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76128912/12002570) can be used to get that type.

Comment: @DavisHerring Surprisingly all compilers [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76192159/21834971) the program when used with concepts. Can you see my new question and tell if it is well formed or not.